# Scrolling & zooming SVG Viewer on Windows?

Tags: windows, image, browser, scroll, svg

We need to view some very large (7200+ pixels) SVGs. Every SVG viewer I've found, including modern web browsers, does not allow us to view the entire image. There aren't any scrollbars, and we do not have the option to zoom.

Is an open source / free application available that could help with viewing the entire SVG image? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you mean SVG? SVG is scalable, meaning it should look the same at any size. Also, 7200 pixels is a meaningless measure for SVG.

Comment: That's nitpicking. An unscaled rendering of SVG that takes 7200px needs to be zoom-able and scrollable in the viewer.

Comment: Actually I'm as confused as Matthew.  I'm still not getting what you mean by an SVG that "takes 7200px to be zoom-able and scrollable"?  Do you mean that rendering it to a 7200x7200 bitmap would make it legible when you zoom and scroll around the bitmap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really do mean SVG, [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add viewBox attribute to the `<svg>` element and wievers will scale the image to the available viewport.

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 7200 7200' ... >
```

You may want to try [Opera SVG Viewer](http://widgets.opera.com/widget/15172/) to preview multiple svg files at once.

Comment: Simply setting a viewbox doesn't work.  A huge svg opened in a browser (not inline html) will crop off image and not scale and not provide scrollbars.   Try something like: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 1000 4000"><line x1="500" y1="0" x2="500" y2="4000" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"/></svg>

Comment: If you add width="1000" and height="4000" then you'll at least get scrollbars.  No scaling though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom css browser extension such as Stylus, you can set up a CSS style for overflow on the root element, which should be `<svg>`:

```
:root {
    overflow:auto !important;
}
```

This is pretty harmless for any html page but you can have it only apply to .svg urls via the url regex filter:

```
^.*[.]svg$
```

Now with this in place, opening an svg in a new tab will apply the style and allow you to scroll around. Zooming in and out should automatically adjust scrollbars.